# SYSIBM.SQLSTATISTICS and SYSIBM.SQLPRIMARYKEYS using most of CPU in DB2 on Windows

Tags: db2, odbc, db2-luw

I have a fairly busy DB2 on Windows server - 9.7, fix pack 11.

About 60% of the CPU time used by all queries in the package cache is being used by the following two statements:

```
CALL SYSIBM.SQLSTATISTICS(?,?,?,?,?,?)
CALL SYSIBM.SQLPRIMARYKEYS(?,?,?,?)
```

I'm fairly decent with physical tuning and have spent a lot of time on SQL tuning on this system as well. The applications are all custom, and educating developers is something I also spend time on.

I get the impression that these two stored procedures are something that perhaps ODBC calls? Reading their descriptions, they also seem like things that are completely unnecessary to do the work being done. The application doesn't need to know the primary key of a table to be able to query it!

Is there anything I can tell my developers to do that will either eliminate/reduce the execution of these or cache the information so that they're not executing against the database millions of times and eating up so much CPU? Or alternately anything I can do at the database level to reduce their impact?

Comment: Do your developers use any particular persistence framework? This sounds like something that JPA or Hibernate would do to retrieve database metadata.

Comment: That is a good question. I will ask.

Comment: You might find this useful: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.dbconn.doc/doc/c0005596.html

Comment: They are using ADO for most of the applications I see executing these stored procedure calls. However, one of the applications I've seen executing it is not.

Comment: Seems the applications are somewhere calling catalog functions like SQLPrimaryKeys, SQLStatistics, etc. See here for a list of the catalog functions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711722(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

6.5 years later, and I have the answer to my own question. This is a side effect of using an ORM. Part of what it does is to discover the database schema. Rails also has a similar workload. In Rails, you can avoid this by using the [schema cache](https://kirshatrov.com/posts/schema-cache/). This becomes particularly important at scale. Not sure if there are equivalencies for other ORMs, but I hope so!